# Rails shorter "time_ago_in_words"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

Is there a different time calculation in rails besides "time_ago_in_words"?? I want to be able to use just 'h' for hours 'd' days 'm' for months... ex. 3d, or 4h, or 5m

My code now...

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
```

Answer (score 17):

The components that make up this string can be localised, and are in the datetime.distance_in_words namespace

For example stick

```
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      x_minutes:
        one: "1m"
        other: "%{count}m"
```

And rails will say 10m instead of 10 minutes. Repeat as needed for hours, seconds days etc. you can check [locales/en.yml](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml) in action_view for all the keys.

If you only want the short format you could create a pseudo locale that only used those keys and use it like so

```
time_ago_in_words created_at, false, :locale => :en_abbrev
```

Comment: Here's a quick sample for this https://gist.github.com/mahemoff/d24b5d7ec156bedffd594c8610178b7e

Comment: Worked for me on Rails 5.2.x

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I don't see it documented at https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words. Is there another official reference somewhere for this?

Answer (score 6):

In the newer versions of rails, you can specify a scope as an option for the  method like so:

```
time_ago_in_words(company.updated_at, scope: 'datetime.distance_in_words.abbrv')
```

Then you just need to have your regular i18n file structured like so:

```
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      abbrv:
        about_x_hours:
          one: ~ 1h
          other: ~ %{count}h
        about_x_months:
          one: ~ 1mo
          other: ~ %{count}mo
        about_x_years:
          one: ~ 1y
          other: ~ %{count}y
        almost_x_years:
...
```

This information is also available in the documentation:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words

Answer (score 2):

Here's some other ways to do it. You run the method like normal, and then you use [gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) on the string.

Chained

```
string.gsub(/ mi.*/, 'm')
      .gsub(/ h.*/, 'h')
      .gsub(/ d.*/, 'd')
      .gsub(/ mo.*/, 'mo')
      .gsub(/ y.*/, 'y')
```

Hash

```
string.gsub(/ .+/, { 
  ' minute'=> 'm', ' minutes'=>'m', 
  ' hour' => 'h', ' hours' => 'h', 
  ' day' => 'd', ' days' => 'd', 
  ' month' => 'mo', ' months' => 'mo', 
  ' year' => 'y', ' years' => 'y' 
})
```

Block

```
string.gsub(/ .+/) { |x| x[/mo/] ? 'mo' : x[1] }
```

They all do the same except for when the string is `"less than a minute"`. The chained solution returns `"less than a minute"`. The hash solution returns `"less"`. The block solution returns `"lesst"`.

Just change the locale file for this one case

```
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      less_than_x_minutes:
        one: '<1m'
```

Or add a return to clause at the top of your method

```
def my_method(string)
  return '<1m' if string == 'less than a minute'
  # code
end
```

Note: Does not include solutions for `include_seconds: true` option.