# Shorter output than time_ago_in_words()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a Ruby/Rails function that shows shorter text than `time_ago_in_words()`?

For example, instead of `5 hours ago` is it possible to get `5h ago` instead?

Comment: if this time object you can use `strftime("%Hh ago")`

Comment: ^ @Monk_Code I don't think that'll work. See: `t = 1.hour.ago` result: **=> Tue, 31 Dec 2013 06:28:01 UTC +00:00**. Now: `t.strftime('%Hh ago')` result: **=> "06h ago"** which is not true at all.

Comment: @Surya just get nonsense)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update to Billy's code. I'd prefer to do it like this:

```
TIME_PATTERN = {' hours'=>'h', ' minutes'=>'m', ' days'=>'d', ' hour'=>'h', ' minute'=>'m', ' day'=>'d'}

def time_ago_converter(words)
  TIME_PATTERN.each_pair do |k, v|
    words.gsub!(k, v)
  end
  words
end
```

in view:

```
<%= time_ago_converter time_ago_in_words(foo.created_at) %>
```

Since, each time you'll be instantiating hash object when time_ago_converter is called. And, by looks of it, this method can be assumed to be called frequently every time the view is rendered. Instead, I'll declare it as a constant once and reuse the same. Please correct me here if I am wrong.

Also, I think this can be done like this as well:

```
TIME_PATTERN = {' hours'=>'h', ' minutes'=>'m', ' days'=>'d', ' hour'=>'h', ' minute'=>'m', ' day'=>'d'}
# or make use of locale:
# TIME_PATTERN = {' hour'=> I18n.t('h'), ' minute'=> I18n.t('m'), ' day'=> I18n.t('d'), ' hours'=> I18n.t('h'), ' minutes'=> I18n.t('m'), ' days'=> I18n.t('d')}

def time_ago_in_words_converter(time)
  word = time_ago_in_words(time)
  TIME_PATTERN.each_pair{ |k, v| word.gsub!(k, v) }
  word
end
```

in view:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words_converter(foo.created_at) %>
```

Cheers!

Comment: If you rearrange `TIME_PATTERN` to have the plurals before the singulars, you can use `gsub` for the body of the method like this: `words.gsub(Regexp.union(TIME_PATTERN.keys), TIME_PATTERN)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice catch. But, from his question I don't think he wants something like this: **5hs ago**.

Comment: Hence rearranging `TIME_PATTERN` as mentioned.

Comment: Yep i agree with @MichaelKohl, the plurals need to be in front of the singulars to avoid having 1ms instead of 1m.

Answer (score 2):

`time_ago_in_words` output words in fixed format. You can write a helper to handle custom need.

```
def time_ago_converter(words)
  pattern = {' hour'=>'h', ' minute'=>'m', ' day'=>'d', 
    ' hours'=>'h', ' minutes'=>'m', ' days'=>'d'}
  pattern.each_pair do |k, v|
    words.gsub!(k, v)
  end
  words
end

time_ago_converter time_ago_in_words(foo.created_at)
```

Update: I added a space before key. Also, both time_ago_in_words and this method is not very efficient as they are not friendly to cache. Suggest to use client side lib to handle time ago if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use I18n locales for same:

Refer the file : https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml

You can modify locales in it accordingly for formats, datetime, about_x_* etc. as per your 'shorter text' requirement.

Comment: Is there a way to have both? i.e. Be able to show the normal version by default and the shorter version on demand?

Comment: You can add the shorter version locales to a different 'locale' say :en_abbrev, and pass options to time_ago_in_words. Something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12597684/985051