# Rails created_at format to show only minute, day, or week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strftime

I'd like to Post's to be displayed either showing how many minutes ago they were posted or weeks ago.

For example, if the post was created 5 minutes ago, it should be displayed as

```
5m
```

5 days ago:

```
5d
```

10 weeks ago:

```
10w
```

and so on.

Previously I was just using `time_ago_in_words`, but would prefer a simpler view.

Comment: I have a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20853768/1721198 may be of some help.

Comment: How do you want 5994 minutes to be displayed?

Comment: I guess for that it'd be 4d, good call though I'll add to question

Comment: A common way is to show up to 59 minutes, after that up to 23 hours, after that up to 6-30 days, after that eighter 52 weeks or 11 months, and after that in years.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#M000297), it will probably help you.

If it doesn't, take a look at [to_formatted_s](http://apidock.com/rails/Date/to_formatted_s).

Hope it helps =]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create your own solution, for example:

In your `ApplicationHelper`:

```
def short_time_ago_in_words(time)
  case time
  when (1.minute.ago)...(Time.now) then "1m"
  when...
  when (Date.today - 1)..(Date.today) then "1d"
  when (Date.today - 7)..(Date.today) then "1w"
  when...
  end
end
```